# Firebase - Disable default email action URL

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a possibility to disable the default email action URL (e.g. `https://example.com/__/auth/action`) template?

The reason for this is that I set up my own email action URL handlers for `verifyEmail`, `recoverEmail` and `resetPassword` on the url `https://example.com/__/auth/action`, however, even though the route works properly on localhost, I get redirected to the default Firebase action URL template after deploying the project to Firebase Hosting.

Therefore, I tried linking to a different subpage such as `https://example.com/__/auth-action` and while this works, the default link `https://example.com/__/auth/action` also is still intact and redirects to the Firebase default template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Firebase support about this issue and the solution is to use a different route than the default "/__auth/action", since the Firebase default handler template will override your custom one. However, even after adding your custom action URL, the default URL is still active and accessible by users.

At the moment there is no option to disable the default action URL. Quote Firebase support:

> Now, I looked into this behavior and currently you can't disable the
> default handler, but it will be a good option for developers that want
> to keep using that path.

Therefore, a feature request to consider this functionality on a future release was filed.